# relational view unavailable in phpmyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I use MAMP and cannot see the "rational view" button usually located between "print view" and "propose table structure"

I tried as indicated in some post on stackoverflow to select innoDB as the storage engine in operation, but it is already selected...

[image]

**how can I fix it?**

here the information about the version I use.
[image]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 4.2.10 (I also added a picture of the version in my question)